# How to push data in the table to axios.post

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to post the data in the table but I keep getting the following in my console.log `testing, undefined`. What am I missing? or is there a better way to get the data to axios.post?

```js
export default {
  props: {
    table: {
      type:Array,
      required: true,
      default: null
    }
  },
  data() {
  },
  methods: {
    submit(item) {
      axios.post('/newitem/${netId}', item)
        .then(response => {
          console.log("testing", response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          // handle the error
        });
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr v-for="(item, index) in table" :key="index">
    <td> {{ item.name }} </td>
    <td> {{ item.source }} </td>
    <td> {{ item.accountId }} </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div>
  <b-button @click="submit(item)">add</b-button>
</div>
```

example of data:

```
  table: [{
      name: 'John',
      source: 'john@example.com',
      accountId: 30
    },
    {
      name: 'Sam',
      source: 'sam@example.com',
      accountId: 25
    },
  ]
```

Comment: Have you checked your network tab for the response of `/newitem/${netId}` call?

Comment: your submit button function outside the table so it cant read variable item. Just add the  variable "table" to it not "item".